# is it possible to ckeck if a member has administrator permission

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

is it possible to check if members of a discord server has administrator permissions in a `for` loop? bcz because i want to ban everyone who has a role that is under my bot in the server of me and my friends. How can i do this?

In my code i have

```
else if (message.content === `${prefix}lmao`)  {
    message.guild.members.cache.map(member => member.ban({reason: 'lol u got banned'}));
```

but i get an error, the error says:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\dasjo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\dasjo\OneDrive\Desktop\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
```

how can i do it, that my bot bans everyoen who has a role that is under my bot?

Comment: `map` is used to create a new array. I recommend using `forEach`

Comment: ok thank u, but the error is still there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Banning a large chunk of members in a guild is not a good idea*

However,

You can use `GuildMembers#forEach` to ban multiple members based on conditions. Based on your question you want to ban those who *do not* have `ADMINISTRATOR`

Use `Promise#catch` to detect a failed ban. `Promise#then` will only fire if the ban was successful

```
const GuildMembers = message.guild.members.cache;

GuildMembers.forEach(member => {
   if (!member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      member.ban({ reason: 'lol u got banned' })
         .then(_ => {
            message.channel.send(`${member.displayName} successfully banned`);
         })
         .catch(err => {
            message.channel.send(`Failed to ban ${member.displayName}`);
            console.log(err);
         });
   }
});
```